# Equivalence of expectations

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I have two **independent** random variables $X$ and $Y$, and a constant term $a$. Furthermore, $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$. I want to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[X+Y/a|aX+Y]\cdot\mathbb{E}[X|aX+Y]\Big]
=\mathbb{E}[X^2].
$$
I would like to execute the towering property of expectation to evaluate this but it doesn't quite work because there are two conditional expectations. How can I show this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, recognize that $E[X + a^{-1}Y|aX + Y] = a^{-1}E[aX + Y|aX + Y] = a^{-1}(aX + Y)$, which is $\sigma(aX + Y)$-measurable, whence can be absorbed into $E[X|aX + Y]$.
It thus follows that
\begin{align}
 & E\left[E[X + a^{-1}Y|aX+ Y]E[X|aX + Y]\right] \\
=& a^{-1}E\left[E[X(aX + Y)|aX + Y]\right] \\
=& a^{-1}E[X(aX + Y)] \tag{1}\label{1} \\
=& a^{-1}E[aX^2] + a^{-1}E[XY] \\
=& E[X^2] + a^{-1}E[X]E[Y] \tag{2}\label{2} \\
=& E[X^2] \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}

In $\eqref{1}$, we used the law of iterative expectations. In $\eqref{2}$, we used the independence of $X$ and $Y$.  In $\eqref{3}$, we used $E[Y] = 0$.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice to see you using `\eqref` :-); +1.